# P5 catch shader compilation errors

Tags: javascript, shader, webgl, p5.js

I am making a shader editor in the web. Users can create their own shaders in a textarea and it will be applied to a webcam.

The problem is that I have no watch to catch shader compilation errors and display them to the user. They just raise an error in developer console.

My code

```
    try {
      newShaderObj = pFive.createShader(defaultVertShader, fragShader)
      pFive.shader(newShaderObj)
    } catch (e) {
      alert(e)
    }
```

The try / catch here doesn't work; I still get this error shown in console, without the `catch` ever running

> p5.min.js:2 Darn! An error occurred compiling the fragment shader:ERROR: 0:4: 'asd' : syntax error

I'm also getting this other error

> p5.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'useProgram' on 'WebGLRenderingContext': parameter 1 is not of type 'WebGLProgram'.

If I introduce a global `window.onerror` handler, I can rescue this one:

```
    window.onerror = (ev, source, lineno, colno, err) => {
      alert(err)
      pFive.shader(defaultValidShader)
    }
```

But it doesn't tell me anything about the underlying compilation error. Also, that `pFive.shader.defaultValidShader` doesn't work, and I have to reload the page to get anything working again.

So, what I would really like to do is validate/compile the shader *before* applying it, and also have a way to handle errors at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out by looking at the source code in p5 Shader class (in the `init` function)

https://github.com/processing/p5.js/blob/64354940c5a116b1b27bbf4c6cb7f04b6c2b9f0a/src/webgl/p5.Shader.js

and ended up with the following code:

```
    newShaderObj = pFive.createShader(defaultVertShader, fragShader)
    shaderError = checkShaderError(shaderObj, fragShader)
    if (shaderError) {
      alert(shaderError)
    } else {
      shaderObj = newShaderObj
      pFive.shader(shaderObj)
    }
```

And the `checkShaderError` function:

```
  checkShaderError = (shaderObj, shaderText) => {
    gl = shaderObj._renderer.GL
    glFragShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER)
    gl.shaderSource(glFragShader, shaderText)
    gl.compileShader(glFragShader)
    if !gl.getShaderParameter(glFragShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS) {
      return gl.getShaderInfoLog(glFragShader)
    }
    return null
  }
```